# Copying a file locally with WMI in C++

Tags: c++, windows, wmi

I want to use the CIM_DataFile object to copy a file in a local computer to a local directory (no remote).

This is my current C++ code:

```cpp
BOOL WmicCopy(char* from, char* to) {
    HRESULT hres;
    BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"CIM_DataFile");
    BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"Copy");
    IWbemClassObject* pCIMDataFile = NULL;
    IWbemClassObject* pCopyMethodClass = NULL;
    IWbemClassObject* pCopyParamsInstance = NULL;
    
    char* query = new char[512];
    ZeroMemory(query, 512);
    strcat(query, "CIM_DataFile.Name=\'");
    strcat(query, from);
    strcat(query, "\'");

    //Get WMI Svc Instance
    IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,
        0,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        debug_printf("Failed to create IWbemLocator object. Error code = 0x%x\n", hres);
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the local root\cimv2 namespace
    // and obtain pointer pSvc to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
        _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        0,
        0,
        &pSvc
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        debug_printf("Could not connect. Error code = 0x%x\n", hres);
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    debug_printf("Connected to wmi namespace.\n");

    // Set security levels for the proxy ------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
        pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
        RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx 
        RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx 
        NULL,                        // Server principal name 
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
        NULL,                        // client identity
        EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        debug_printf("Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x%x\n", hres);
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    //Get CIM DataFile object
    debug_printf("Running query: %s\n", query);
    hres = pSvc->GetObjectA(_bstr_t(query), 0, NULL, &pCIMDataFile, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        debug_printf("Failed to get object from file path: 0x%x\n", hres);
    }

    // set up to call the Win32_Process::Create method

    // Create the values for the in parameters
    VARIANT varTo;
    varTo.vt = VT_BSTR;
    varTo.bstrVal = _bstr_t(to);

    hres = pCIMDataFile->GetMethod(MethodName, 0,
        &pCopyMethodClass, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        debug_printf("Failed to get method: 0x%x\n", hres);
    }
    hres = pCopyMethodClass->SpawnInstance(0, &pCopyParamsInstance);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        debug_printf("Failed to spawn instance: 0x%x\n", hres);
    }

    // Store the value for the in parameters
    hres = pCopyParamsInstance->Put(L"FileName", 0,
        &varTo, 0);
    if (FAILED(hres)) {
        debug_printf("Failed to set param value: 0x%x\n", hres);
    }
    debug_printf("File to copy to is: %ls\n", V_BSTR(&varTo));

    // Execute Method
    IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
        
    hres = pSvc->ExecMethod(
        _bstr_t(query),       //strObjectPath
        MethodName,      //strMethodName
        0,               //iFlags
        NULL,            //IWbemContext *pCt
        pCopyParamsInstance,//IWbemClassObject *pInParams
        &pOutParams,     //IWbemClassObject *pOutParams
        NULL);           //ppCallResult

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        debug_printf("Could not execute method. Error code = 0x%x\n", hres);
        VariantClear(&varTo);
        SysFreeString(ClassName);
        SysFreeString(MethodName);
        if (pCopyMethodClass)
            pCopyMethodClass->Release();
        if (pCopyParamsInstance)
            pCopyParamsInstance->Release();
        pCIMDataFile->Release();
        pOutParams->Release();
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // To see what the method returned,
    // use the following code.  The return value will
    // be in &varReturnValue
    VARIANT varReturnValue = {};
    ZeroMemory(&varReturnValue, sizeof(VARIANT));
    hres = pOutParams->Get(_bstr_t(L"ReturnValue"), 0,
        &varReturnValue, NULL, 0);

    

    // Clean up
    //--------------------------
    //VariantClear(&varTo);
    //VariantClear(&varReturnValue);
    if (pCopyMethodClass)
        pCopyMethodClass->Release();
    if (pCopyParamsInstance)
        pCopyParamsInstance->Release();
    SysFreeString(MethodName);
    SysFreeString(ClassName);
    pCIMDataFile->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pSvc->Release();
    return TRUE;
}
```

This is the output, where it fails with WBEM_E_ILLEGAL_OPERATION at hres = pCIMDataFile->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, &pCopyMethodClass, NULL);

Full output:

```
Connected to wmi namespace.
Running query: CIM_DataFile.Name='C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe'
Failed to get method: 0x8004101e
```

This is the working Visual Basic code (copies cmd.exe to bab.exe on my desktop) that I'm trying to write in C++:

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
' Obtain an instance of the the class 
' using a key property value.
Set objShare = objWMIService.Get("CIM_DataFile.Name='C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe'")

' Obtain an InParameters object specific
' to the method.
Set objInParam = objShare.Methods_("Copy"). _
    inParameters.SpawnInstance_()


' Add the input parameters.
objInParam.Properties_.Item("FileName") =  "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\baba.exe"

' Execute the method and obtain the return status.
' The OutParameters object in objOutParams
' is created by the provider.
Set objOutParams = objWMIService.ExecMethod("CIM_DataFile.Name='C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe'", "Copy", objInParam)

' List OutParams
Wscript.Echo "Out Parameters: "
Wscript.echo "ReturnValue: " & objOutParams.ReturnValue
```

Why does a similar GetMethod call in VB work, but not in C++?
(Pardon the messy error handling in the C++ code, was trying to get a structure out before properly writing a cleanup jump)

Comment: Why do you want to use WMI for this, instead of using the much simpler `CopyFile/Ex()` function?

Comment: It's for a proof of concept in a research project (specifically to use wmi to write files). I'm not just trying to copy a file for utility's sake